# Android.Location.toString() interpretation of `et`

Tags: android, geolocation

When I use .toString() method on `Location` object I have results like this:

```
Location[gps 01.234567,12.234567 
         acc=14 
         et=+2d23h36m34s870ms 
         alt=123.0 
         vel=0.0 
         {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=40]}
         ]
```

(I added newlines for better readability)

I guess (after some research here: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)):

- `acc=14` is accurracy in meters
- `vel=0` is velocity in meters/second
- `alt=123` is altitude above WGS reference ellipsoid in meters

---

But what is `et=+2d23h36m34s870ms`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to javadocs:

> /**
>        * Return the time of this fix, in elapsed real-time since system boot.
>        *
>        *
>
> This value can be reliably compared to
>        * {@link android.os.SystemClock#elapsedRealtimeNanos},
>        * to calculate the age of a fix and to compare Location fixes. This
>        * is reliable because elapsed real-time is guaranteed monotonic for
>        * each system boot and continues to increment even when the system
>        * is in deep sleep (unlike {@link #getTime}.
>        *
>        *
>
> All locations generated by the {@link LocationManager}
>        * are guaranteed to have a valid elapsed real-time.
>        *
>        * @return elapsed real-time of fix, in nanoseconds since system boot.
>        */

```
public long getElapsedRealtimeNanos() {
    return mElapsedRealtimeNanos;
}
```

`toString` code that is relevant to `et`

```
if (mElapsedRealtimeNanos == 0) {
    s.append(" et=?!?");
} else {
    s.append(" et=");
    TimeUtils.formatDuration(mElapsedRealtimeNanos / 1000000L, s);
}
```

And by the way the meaning of it is probably *how long it has been since the location was last updated*

Comment: "how long it has been since the location was last updated" that would be weird, 3 days... I'm not sure if this is it.

Comment: Well this is the docs, code and recent stack overflow questions are saying

Comment: And why not? Notice that the time is elapsed time since reboot

Comment: Oooh you are right. Thats time from reboot, not from last update :)