What does the `et` timestamp stand for in the Android Location object?
I got the following location object from LocationResult, and I was wondering what the et timestamp is?
Location[fused 37.421998,-122.084000, hAcc=12.236 et=+3d16h46m21s252ms alt=154.0 vAcc=1.6407026 vel=1.2971644 sAcc=1.5 bear=15.871763 bAcc=45.0]
I couldn't find any useful information in the docs either.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321353/android-location-tostring-interpretation-of-et

If you look at the source code to Location, you will see that toString() includes:
        s.append(" et=");
        TimeUtils.formatDuration(getElapsedRealtimeMillis(), s);

So, et is the value of getElapsedRealtimeMillis(). According to the documentation, that is "the time of this fix in milliseconds of elapsed realtime since system boot".
